# angularfire2 XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angularfire2

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, angularfire2

I am getting the following console errors when installing angularfire2 to my project. 
I have updated node and also migrated to ng4 but still same issues. 
I added the environments folder with environment.ts which is not present in the quick start setup and added firebase config details.

I experience the same errors when trying to install angularfire2 to the latest angular quick start.

I have tried to troubleshoot based on advice for `Traceur not found : XHR (404 not found) error`which was closest issue I could find, but without success. Not sure if this is similar issue.

Could someone advise what’s going wrong and how to resolve this?

Thanks

npm: **3.8.9**

node: **v6.10.3**

typescript Version: **2.3.2**

**Console Error**

```
(index):18 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angularfire2
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angularfire2
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1032:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:414:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:181:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:476:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/angularfire2 as "angularfire2" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1032:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:414:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:181:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:476:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/angularfire2 as "angularfire2" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
// import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), // imports firebase/app needed for everything
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, // imports firebase/database, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
 ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

**systems.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Full angular-quickstart files with attempted angularfire2 install can be found [here](https://github.com/fivedoor/angularquickstart)

Answer (score 0):

Add under `// other libraries` in `system.config.js` path to angularfire2 main script from your module directory.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up with was to create a brand new project using [angularfire & angular cli installation and setup](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md). 
I then migrated my app files from the project I had built from angular's quick start.

I found [this blog](https://blog.khophi.co/angularfire2-authentication/) helpful for anyone trying to add angularfire2 to a project built using angular quickstart. That helped initially resolve the 404 error but I ran into more tracer errors so eventually opted for the above solution.